# Testing configuration for connections in SSIS 2005 packages

Tags: configuration, ssis, connection

I am trying to make a test that loops through all our ssis 2005 packages and identify if any connections are using incorrect servernames.
In the packages we have two connections that should be linked to one configuration in a sql server table.
In the configuration table there are two rows with different package paths but the same configuration name. When I read the package programatically I can't find any link between the connections and the configurations and the connections seem to show the "local" connectionstring before the configurations has taken effect. Is there any way that I can get the connectionstrings that will be used when the package is run or find the link between the connection and the configuration?

Here is the code that I am debugging:

```
string path = @"C:\Package1.dtsx";

Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new    
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();

Package p;            
p = app.LoadPackage(path, null);
```

Config part of file:

```
<DTS:Configuration>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConfigurationType">7</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConfigurationString">"BI_MR_Native";"[MetaGrensesnitt].[PakkeKonfigurasjon]";"Test_ConnectionString";</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConfigurationVariable"></DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">Test_Connectionstring</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{47CA3739-654E-48E5-9B3A-0DE8711127D9}</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="Description"></DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName"></DTS:Property>
</DTS:Configuration>
```

Contents of our configuration table for this configuration:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsopz.jpg

Comment: What is your problem related to programming and what you have tried? show your code.

Comment: What do you mean by reading the package programmatically?   What are you doing exactly, and what is the problem exactly?   This question is very high-level and vague.

Comment: Yes the packages themselves contain 'design time' information only. The configurations part of the package will point at a database config, Find that first (I suggest via a search of the XML in a XML or text editor). The only bit I'm confused about is " In the configuration table there are two rows with different package paths but the same configuration name". You don't normally put a package path in the config table. Normally configs don't know anything about packages. Anyway find your XML config nodes and post back

Comment: This link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc895212.aspx, says  _PackagePath: The path that points to the property being configured_. So `Package path` points at a property inside the package. So one row is configuring the connection called `BI_Test_Net` and the other row is configuring a connection called `BI_Test_Native`. In your posted package XML, the contents of those XML nodes are pointing at these rows. So you need to: 1. Write some code that inspects these config values in the package; 2. Connect to the DB indicated in the config and 3. Check the config entries are correct.

Comment: I cant see that the configuration is pointing to the connections. Is there something that I am missing? The problem is that there is only one configuration, and it is either connected to one or two connections and I can't find a way to see if only one of the connections are connected to the configuration or if both of them are. We have a lot of packages who use the same configurations and two rows in the db only tells us that at least one package have configurations for both.